# The name 'model' does not exist in the current context ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view, model, rendering

I'm trying to render the data collection for my project.

The sources:

- http://ideone.com/8LbZuH ( View )
- http://ideone.com/zaqHeE ( Controller )
- http://ideone.com/P4iEkO ( Model )

The data binding in the controller does run pretty fine, but I can't render the model in `View`, which was returned from the `Controller`.

I'm getting such an error:

`the name 'model' does not exist in the current context`

I don't understand **why?** I'm getting such an error, because the other model rendering for another View works well, but not this one.

Who can explain me, what is the reason for occurring my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `Model` not `model`:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
    <td>@item.ContractGuid</td>
    <td>@item.SenderId</td>
    <td>@item.ContractStatus</td>
    <td>@item.CreditEnd</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Lowercase `model` is used to define type of model, which will be passed to the view (e.g. `@model List<MvcApplication6.Models.ContractPlain>`), whereas *capital* `Model` is used to access it (e.g. `Model.First()`)

The other thing is that `Html.DisplayText` doesn't work this way, so you can either remove it (like I did) or replace it with `Html.DisplayFor`

Comment: it has stopped showing me that error, but it doesn't render the data, it's strange, because in the controller (when I debug it), it has data, I can prove it: http://s16.postimg.org/pfkctak45/Screenshot_582.png

Comment: @GeloVolro My mistake, it seems that `DisplayText` works differetly (I've never used it). Just remove `Html.DisplayText` (so you'll have e.g. `@item.ContractGuid`)

Comment: Thanks! :) It does work right now, look here: http://s8.postimg.org/6xlkd7zhx/Screenshot_583.png A lot of thanks :)